# jQuery Mobile - PhoneGap - Google maps not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an issue when this application is bundled via PhoneGap the google maps doesn't load, however when viewing the same page via safari browser on the iPhone it works.

I have debugged this application and identified the latlng doesn't get initialized:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longituide);
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/kfcj4/
```

Please not that the map page is linked from an external page. So for whatever reason it doesn't intialize latlng..can you please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Within the config.xml I have the following <access origin="*" />

Answer (score 1):

finally figured this out.. you need to have this inside the index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```